# Deploy Next Js to cPanel Shared Hosting

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I followed this tutorial in order to deploy my nextjs app to shared hosting on cPanel.

```
Road map for deploying on cPanel Next App with server-side rendering (not only static) :

Build locally (next build)
Copy into html_folder all your project directory (not only the build folder, and except node_modules of course) :

public_html
    my_project
        .next
        src
        server.js
        package.json
        ...

Note: A custom server is needed as cPanel needs a startup file (use the next's default one)

    create your node application ("setup node.js app") with options :
    Application root : public_html/my_project
    Application startup file : server.js
    ...
    "Run NPM install" to create node_modules packages
    Finally "Start App"

package.json with the start command :

"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
}
```

However, visiting my website after going through the entire process gives me this error:
[image]

Comment: When you click technical details for the administrator of the website - what do you get?

Comment: I get: Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger(R) application server.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is run `next build && next export` and put the contents of the out folder in the public_html folder or /var/www/html/, /sites-available/, etc, depending on setup.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure to copy the **.next** folder, in the cpanel's folder,  like this:

my_project --> folder in cpanel
_________
| .next   | --> this folder
___________
src
server.js
package.json
...

If you can't see this folder in your project, enable the option to show hidden files.

Comment: yuleica sojo, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).